# DCT coefficient and motion vector extraction in encoded domain

Tags: c++, opencv, machine-learning, ffmpeg, computer-vision

I want to extract DCT coefficients and motion vectors from a MPEG 4 video without decoding. I have searched for an answer and haven't found anything useful.

Please be kind enough to share any idea, possibilities of doing this task or a code.

Some how I was able to write a code to read encoded code using ffmpeg.

```
void CFfmpegmethods::VideoRead(){
    //cout << "this is video read" << endl;

    const char *url = "H:/Sanduni_projects/ad_2.mp4";

    AVFormatContext *s = NULL;
    int ret = avformat_open_input(&s, url, NULL, NULL);
    if (ret < 0)
        //abort();

    AVDictionary *options = NULL;

    av_dict_set(&options, "video_size", "640x480", 0);
    av_dict_set(&options, "pixel_format", "rgb24", 0);

    if (avformat_open_input(&s, url, NULL, &options) < 0){
        //abort();
    }

    av_dict_free(&options);

    AVDictionaryEntry *e;

    if (e = av_dict_get(options, "", NULL, AV_DICT_IGNORE_SUFFIX)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Option %s not recognized by the demuxer.\n", e->key);
        //abort();
    }

    avformat_close_input(&s);   
}
```

Comment: This is a help site share your code or  show us what you tried yet. Then only we can help you.

Comment: I just want to know whether is it possible to extract above features from a video in compressed domain without any decoding process. That's all.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to extract motion vectors as follows. Here I generate an array using coordinates. That is initial and destination position of vectors.

```
static int MV_generation(const AVPacket *pkt)
{
    double x_src_val = 0;
    double y_src_val = 0;
    double x_dst_val = 0;
    double y_dst_val = 0;

int ret = avcodec_send_packet(video_dec_ctx, pkt);

while (ret >= 0){

    ret = avcodec_receive_frame(video_dec_ctx, frame);

    if (ret == AVERROR(EAGAIN) || ret == AVERROR_EOF) {
        break;
    }

    if (ret >= 0) {
        AVFrameSideData *sd;
        sd = av_frame_get_side_data(frame, AV_FRAME_DATA_MOTION_VECTORS);

        if (sd) {
            const AVMotionVector *mvs = (const AVMotionVector *)sd->data;
            int size_sd = sd->size;

            }

        av_frame_unref(frame);
    }
}
return 0;
```

}

Comment: This is my code up to now. I can read encoded video and I wrote data into a text file. But the data that is written there is not readable.